# Two navigation occurred when I navigate to ASP.Net application, any idea why that happens?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, navigation, xbap

I have two applications WPF - xBap one and ASP.Net one.

When I'm doing navigation from xBap to ASP.Net:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:14496/Default.aspx", 
                                        UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

**Two navigation is occurred in the ASP.Net application:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!IsPostBack)
             File.AppendAllText("C:\\log.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                            "(SessionID: " + Session.SessionID + ")" + 
                            Environment.NewLine);
     }
 }
```

The result in log.txt:

```
8/4/2011 10:45:53 AM(SessionID: jnvq2q5g0tt415hzxtdxrird)
8/4/2011 10:45:53 AM(SessionID: e0i13wsxwbpqyxtc3xrh5zcq)
```

---

This behavior causes a problem to me, any idea how to prevent that?

---

The environment:

Dot Net 4.0, IE 9

Comment: Are you not maybe calling the Navigate twice?

Comment: @Jethro : Of course no, I edited the code, try if if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Check the AutoEventWireUp attribute in the Page directive.

Change it to `False` then run it.